# Updating record in MySQL using node.js and rest approach

Tags: mysql, node.js, crud

Short task description: I need to update the record in MySQL DB using the Node.js by the id of this record. The data for update are sent in JSON format using RESTEASY. I wrote the following code:

```
app.put('/:enablerId', function(req, res){
    var jsondata = req.body;
    var enablerid = req.params.enablerId;
    connection.query("UPDATE enablers SET ? WHERE id=?", [jsondata, enablerid], function(error, results){
        if(error) {
            console.log('Query error');
            } else {
            console.log('Updated ' + results.affectedRows + ' row ');
            }
    });
});
```

Response, that I get 0 rows are affected, in fact, nothing has been updated.

I've got an impression, that problem should be somehow connected to proper url attribute

```
app.put('/:enablerId', function(req, res)
```

**If so, general question how to get the id from url?** However, I am not sure. I am a bit lost, will be grateful for any help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `jsondata` look like? Usually your `Set` statement will include `column =` and then the incoming data to update. I'm not familiar with `node.js`, but the `Update` statement doesn't look right.

Comment: jsondata is a variable containing the body of json request, which I want to put into the mysql db instead of the previous record.